# NoMethodError in BlogsController#show

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project blog of mine. I am a novice developer using Ruby on Rails....

I am install a slugging gem and then installed the devise gem for auth.. I think this is an auth error but I have no idea what is really happening. I can get the post to show on my index view, but when I try to click the link to the show view it present this error... Please Help!!!

Below is my controller, routes and model....

The error I keep getting is

> NoMethodError in BlogsController#show
>
> ```
> case filter
>   when Symbol
>     lambda { |target, _, &blk| target.send filter, &blk }
>   when String
>     l = eval "lambda { |value| #{filter} }"
>     lambda { |target, value| target.instance_exec(value, &l) }
> ......
> ```

**My CONTROLLER**

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @blog = Blog.all 
  end

  def new 
    @blog = Blog.new
  end 

  def create
    current_user.blogs.create(blog_params)
    redirect_to blogs_path
  end 

  def show 
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.user != current_user
      return render text: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end
  end

  def update
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if @blog.user != current_user
      return render text: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end

    @blog.update_attributes(blog_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.user != current_user
      return render text: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end

    @blog.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

private

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :blogs
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'portfolio#index'

end
```

**MODEL**

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are using friendly id gem, please, make sure that you properly configured your Blog model according to the gem readme and run the migration to include the slug field into the model.

Also, if you have previous records without slug, open your rails console and run:

```
Blog.find_each(&:save)
```